# node.js conflicts: /sbin/node vs /usr/bin/node

Tags: apt, nodejs

I have two Ubuntu 12.10 machines: machine A is a VMWare VM and machine B is and old Acer laptop. On both machines, I installed node using apt-get. However machine A installs the main binary as `/usr/bin/node` and machine B as `/usr/bin/nodejs`. Here are some behaviors I observed:

1. Both machine returns `/usr/bin/node` in response to the `which node` command. However, there is no such file on machine B.
2. Issuing the command `node` works for machine A, not B. On B, I have to use `nodejs` instead.
3. On B, there is a binary called /sbin/node, A does not have it.

These behaviors causes inconsistency problem when developing on both machines. For now, I worked around by renaming the binaries on B as such:

```
sudo mv /sbin/node /sbin/node-sbin
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Is there a way to really fix this, so that node will be installed as `/usr/bin/node` instead of `/usr/bin/nodejs`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On Ubuntu 13.10 all answers above did not work for me.
It finally worked when I installed nodejs-legacy

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

This correctly provided `/usr/bin/node` for me, so that e. g. `nodemon` can be used.

Comment: Any idea why we need to install this? Does it actually creates the symlink somehow? Why did node change the name of its executable to nodejs?

Comment: The name "node" conflicted with a much older program. See https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2012/07/msg00002.html and Leftium's answer below.

Answer (score 37):

**update:** modified instructions below to use the `nodejs-legacy` package.([more info about node-legacy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21171188/117030))

**Try completely removing the conflicting node package:**

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove node
sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs-legacy
sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs

sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy

# Confirm it worked
node --version       # v0.10.13
ls -la `which node`  # ... /usr/bin/node -> /etc/alternatives/node
```

---

This happened to me when I unwittingly installed the non-node.js `node` package. Although I did `apt-get remove node` before installing the correct `nodejs` package, I guess the `--purge` argument is required.

[Background info](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager#ubuntu-mint-elementary-os):

> There is a naming conflict with the node package (Amateur Packet Radio
>   Node Program), and the nodejs binary has been renamed from node to
>   nodejs. You'll need to symlink /usr/bin/node to /usr/bin/nodejs or you
>   could uninstall the Amateur Packet Radio Node Program to avoid that
>   conflict.

Comment: Thank you for the background info. At this point, I don't have any of these machines to try on, but I hope I can revisit some day soon.

Comment: This doesn't get you a `/usr/bin/node` in Ubuntu 13.10. @user229115's answer below works, though.

Comment: So with Ubuntu 13.10 `sudo apt-get install nodejs nodejs-legacy` will give you the `node` binary as node.js
But if you already installed the `node` (Amateur Packet Radio Node Program) you'll obviously need to remove it.

Comment: Seems like this answer doesn't work anymore...

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger: I updated my answer. I think the combination of both purging the 'misconfigured' packages and installing the `nodejs-legacy` package will work.

Comment: Thanks it is very clear. Indeed it works when installing the `nodejs-lecacy` package which may be only a symlink to the `nodejs` executable actually...

Comment: I made my own symlink, after discovering that "apt-get install node" didn't do what I thought it did.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately for me, creating a symlink did not work. What did work for me though was creating an alias. In `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` (if `~/.bashrc` loads this file), just add the following line:

```
alias node="nodejs"
```

Restart your bash session by typing `bash` into the console and your alias will now work.

Comment: When I created a symlink, it did not work until I started another terminal. Try restarting your terminal... or my answer that works without symlinks/aliases ^^

Comment: @Leftium: You also need to run: `source ~/.bashrc` to reload the .bashrc file (if you want to avoid restarting the terminal) [read more..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518127/how-do-i-reload-bashrc-without-logging-out-and-back-in)

Comment: Symlinking at a new location almost certainly needs a `hash node` invocation in your existing terminals, because modern shells remember the location of commands that have been previously looked up in PATH. The `hash` builtin command in such shells tells them to redo the lookup, and remember the new location.

Answer (score 7):

I think this is it:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/node node /usr/bin/nodejs 10
```

Using Debian alternatives.

Comment: Thanks.  This is the most direct way to remedy Ubuntu's decision on this matter.

Comment: @drew it looks like Ubuntu followed Debian's decision on this based on the Ubuntu bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/node/+bug/1030421 .

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but for up-to-date info...

If you install node.js using the recommend method from the [node github installation readme](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager), it suggests following the instructions on the [nodesource blog article](https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories), rather than installing from the out of date apt-get repo, node.js should run using the `node` command, as well as the `nodejs` command, without having to make a new symlink.

This method from article is:

```
# Note the new setup script name for Node.js v0.12
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -

# Then install with:
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Note that this is for v0.12, which will get likely become outdated in the not to distant future.

Also, if you're behind a corporate proxy (like me) you'll want to add the -E option to the sudo command, to preserve the env vars required for the proxy:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo -E bash -
```

Answer (score 1):

On **ubuntu 14.04** I had the same node problem. I had not working "node", and working "nodejs". I just did

```
sudo apt-get remove node
```

and right after that, node was running, and nodejs is running too :)
I'm new to linux and that is a misstery to me. However Bower is running!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo getconf LONG_BIT
sudo uname -p
```

- Confirm your CPU architecture
- Find your node.js distribution in directory tree at https://nodejs.org/dist/ (note: various versions of various node.js distributions for various CPU architectures)

My desktop is currently Ubuntu 15.10 AMD64, so I will use the following URL in my installation example (again, distrib's vary):

```
sudo wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v5.0.0/node-v5.0.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Then change directory to *your* download directory:

```
sudo cd /home/name/Downloads
```

From your download directory, execute the following:

```
sudo tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xzf node-v5.0.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Confirm your node.js installation with the following:

```
sudo ls -l /usr/local/bin/node
sudo ls -l /usr/local/bin/npm
```

---

ref. http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/install-nodejs-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: -1 Only the `tar` command needs `sudo`.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for that better way - the best way for me!