# Node executables not doing anything

Tags: nodejs

I have some node executables installed on an Ubuntu server but whenever I try to execute them nothing happens. I don't even get an error message. I know they're in my path because `which executable_name` works. When I do which -a node I get two outputs:

```
/usr/sbin/node  
/usr/bin/node
```

I feel like this has something to do with the problem but I have no idea what to do. Help.

Comment: more information here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/235655/node-js-conflicts-sbin-node-vs-usr-bin-node

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/320271/214873):

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove node
sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs
sudo apt-get install nodejs

# Confirm it worked
node --version       # v0.10.13
ls -la `which node`  # ... /usr/bin/node -> /etc/alternatives/node
```

Solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Probably `sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy` would also do what you want.  See http://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2012/07/msg00002.html