# Why doesn't JSLint/JSHint work in Ubuntu?

Tags: environment-variables, javascript, nodejs, environment

I installed as described [here](http://infoheap.com/jslint-command-line-on-ubuntu-linux/) and other places, but after using npm to install jslint, jshint, neither will work. Running "jslint", I only get:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

Is there something wrong with the Ubuntu 13.10 repo, or do I have to set up some PATH variable myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to a conflict with an older "node" package, nodejs gets installed as `nodejs` instead of `node`, the latter being what **jshint** is looking for.

Try this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

For more information, see:

- [node.js conflicts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235655/node-js-conflicts-sbin-node-vs-usr-bin-node) (the node --purge solution didn't work for me on 13.04, hence the symlink above)
- [Issue reported on jshint's Github](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1230) "Most likely the Node binary is not in your PATH."

Answer (score 3):

The issue is tracked on [github](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/1230) where they also give an alternative solution that worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```

Comment: worked for me too.