# How can I get jshint to work?

Tags: 14.04, nodejs, jshint

I installed jshint using `sudo npm install -g jshint`, and it seems to have worked:

```
$which jshint
/usr/local/bin/jshint
```

Yet running `jshint` or its full path equivalent doesn't seem to do anything. It doesn't give an error, either--it just does nothing:

```
$jshint
$jshint --help
$jshint --verbose
$jshint --debug

$jshint admin.js
$jshint admin.js --verbose
$/usr/local/bin/jshint admin.js
```

I also tried symlinking nodejs per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390062/why-doesnt-jslint-jshint-work-in-ubuntu):

```
$sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

$jshint admin.js --verbose
$jshint admin.js
$jshint --help
$man jshint
No manual entry for jshint
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
```

What am I missing here?

Edit: here's the output from `apt-cache policy nodejs npm`. I'm just using the standard Ubuntu 14.04 packages, so there's nothing very special about this:

```
└─>apt-cache policy nodejs npm
nodejs:
  Installed: 0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1
  Candidate: 0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
npm:
  Installed: 1.3.10~dfsg-1
  Candidate: 1.3.10~dfsg-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.3.10~dfsg-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy nodejs npm`?

Comment: nodejs:
  Installed: 0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1
  Candidate: 0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
npm:
  Installed: 1.3.10~dfsg-1
  Candidate: 1.3.10~dfsg-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.3.10~dfsg-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: @Jon Please post the result of command into body of your question. in this case the result is not understandable. thanks

Comment: @KasiyA: added. I can't imagine it'll be that helpful, though, since the versions are no different from the standard 14.04 versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The official repos are a mess...

Installing Node and npm through the official repositories has always given me trouble. I suspect that this could be due to tools depending on `node`, when the actual command on Ubuntu is `nodejs`, which is why creating a symlink *should* work.  It worked for me in my quick test in a virtual machine, but since it didn't work for you, let's try something else...

### So, install Node.JS a different way

I generally prefer to install Node on Ubuntu using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).  This avoids the issue of the `node` command not being defined on Ubuntu, and it avoids [the permissions mess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16151018/388639) that requires using `sudo` to install npm modules.

#### Do the following to get back to a clean slate:

Remove any global modules you've installed with npm ([instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22290968/388639)):

```
sudo npm list -g --depth=0. | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}' | awk -F '@' '{print $1}'  | sudo xargs npm remove -g
```

Remove symlinked node folder:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/node
```

Uninstall the copies of `nodejs` and `npm` that you installed through Ubuntu's repositories:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs npm
```

Clean up any other cruft:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

At this point, `which node`, `which nodejs`, `which npm`, and `which jshint` should all return nothing.

#### Reinstall Node, skipping the official repositories

Grab the latest copy of NVM (you may need to `sudo apt-get install curl` first):

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.15.0/install.sh | bash
```

Tell your shell to use `nvm`

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Then install a node version

```
nvm install 0.12 # or whatever the latest version is
```

And tell nvm which version of Node you want to use

```
nvm use 0.12
```

Now you should be able to run Node with the `node` command, you should be able to install modules globally without `sudo`, and you should end up with a working copy of jshint.

If you don't want to run `nvm use v0.12` every time you start a new terminal session, you can add `nvm use v` to your `~/.bashrc`. The `v` isn't special, it will just match `v*` and find the latest version. Alternatively you could hard-code a specific version.

Comment: after following your guide, every new shell session requires me to explicitly tell shell to use node from nvm by running "nvm use v0.10". Or the session will say node is not installed and recommended me to install it using apt-get. Anyway I can make it use the node.js from nvm by default in every shell session? I thought of aliasing node to the binary in ~/nvm/v0.10.38/ , but it doesn't seem to be a good solution?

Comment: @jimchim Open up `~/.bashrc` and add the line `nvm use v`. The `v` isn't special, but it should match any version (e.g. `v0.12.2`) so nvm should pick the latest.