# alias of nodejs as node on 14.04

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, alias, nodejs

I installed `nodejs` with `apt-get` on `14.04`

When I do `nodejs -v`

```
v0.10.25
```

and when i do `node -v`

```
node : command not found.
```

So I want to alias of `nodejs` to `node`

I inserted a line in `~/.bashrc`

```
alias node=nodejs
```

Now I can access `nodejs` with `node` in a terminal.

But in my project, i use `grunt` which fires `nodemon` via `gruntfile.js`.
Now `nodemon` tries to run `node` instead of `nodejs`

So again I get the same problem `node : command not found`.

So the alias doesn't work for non-interactive non-login shells.

Where should I make the alias for this specific purpose and get my problem solved?

Comment: Please add the same alias in `/etc/profile` and `restart`; after changing any `rc` file or profile file you must source it.

Comment: @Jord i edited /etc/profile with same alias and restarted. But still the problem is same.

Comment: Several years late, but... aliases won't (normally) work in a non-interactive shell: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1615973/7222080 Follow the symlink advice in the answers.

Answer (score 12):

Recently fixed this using `nodejs-legacy`.

Run the following command:

`sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy`

This should fix it.

Answer (score 11):

Well curiously, I have a `node`. It's an alternatives system symlink and I'm not quite sure how I got it (in a way that you don't). It was a while since I installed it so perhaps I followed [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04) or one like it... Who knows!

You could just [write a little bash alias](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias?rq=1) but that'll only work for one user at a time. It might just make more sense to add it as as symlink globally. I'm not sure there's any value going through the alternatives system so we can just plonk one in `/usr/local/bin` (this is where non-package-managed binaries should go):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

---

Edit: That *SO post* I talked about actually links back to [one of ours](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235655/node-js-conflicts-sbin-node-vs-usr-bin-node/320271#320271) which might be relevant. It suggests installing `nodejs-legacy` is the way forward.

Comment: Find the location of nodejs via `whereis nodejs` then do
`ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs ~/bin/node` (yes, no `sudo` there); replace `/usr/bin/nodejs` with the path your nodejs is at

Comment: going backwards is not the way forward

Answer (score 0):

Since the bin directory is already in the `PATH`, you can simply create a symlink called node in the `~/bin` directory linking to the actual binary.

```
 ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs ~/bin/node
```