# Link created to `nodejs` with `node` not working

Tags: bash, alias, nodejs

I'm creating 3 VM's. I set up the first two with nodejs/npm but am having problems with the third. (Note: I realize cloning would have been far more expedient, but that's outside of scope of question.)

In the third, I've installed nodejs and npm using the `sudo apt-get install` method for each. After installing both I ran `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node` to link `node` to `nodejs`. Unfortunately, after performing this `node` fails to work; `node -v` returns nothing while `nodejs -v` returns `v0.10.25`.

Any leads as to what error was made or how to resolve? I've tried both `unlink`ing and removing and recreating `/usr/bin/node` multiple times.

Note: Similar problem listed here ([alias of nodejs as node on 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477577/alias-of-nodejs-as-node-on-14-04)), but mine is different enough to support a new topic, I believe.

Comment: Thanks Pieter, you're right. The selected answer's suggestion of installing `nodejs-legacy` resolved this issue. Fantastic; thanks again. I'll accept the duplicate warning for this question given it is indeed a duplicate.